The meaning of these 16 bytes in the `.data` segment
I wrote a C++ program (t.cc) that only has an empty main function:
int main() {

}

I used g++ t.cc -o a.out to compile it into an executable program, and then used objdump --section=.data -s a.out to view its .data segment. I found that there were 16 bytes of data in the .data segment:
Contents of section .data:
 4000 00000000 00000000 08400000 00000000  .........@......

As far as I know, the .data segment stores initialized global variables and static variables. However, none of these variables are defined in the program I wrote. So, I want to know what the contents of these 16 bytes represent.
I want to know what the contents of these 16 bytes represent.

Compile and link with gcc -g, look at the objdump -x a.out output, and see which symbols point to these bytes. My prediction is that they are from glibc.

"I used g++ t.cc -o a.out to compile" - So you did an unoptimized debug build. That that is not optimal is unsurprising. That's what you do when you need to be able to use your debugger reliably and don't care about binary size or performance, you just want to be able to debug the thing easily. For a release build where you care about size and performance you'd do something like g++ -O3 -flto t.cc, to let the compiler and linker optimize stuff (LTO isn't really going to do much for this contrived/trivial example, but in real life it will) so how does that change things for you?

@JesperJuhl You can know it's not optimal but still be curious, right? :-)

Repeating the experiment on my system, I get:
$ objdump -x foo | grep .data
 23 .data         00000010  0000000000004000  0000000000004000  00003000  2**3

So 0x10 (16) bytes starting at address 0x4000.
Let's ask nm next:
$ nm --numeric-sort foo
...
0000000000004000 D __data_start
0000000000004000 W data_start
0000000000004008 D __dso_handle

So 0x4000 is the symbol __data_start, which points to the start of the .data section. It effectively contains its own address.
0x4008 contains a symbol called __dso_handle. I have no idea but this answer seems to have a good grip.
